# Javascript Analytics Code Manipulation (G. Analytics)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, data-manipulation

for my job I am doing an research projekt on the validity of Google Analytics (mostly in regards to the verified reports on flippa) --> see if it is possible to completly fake G. Analytics (a simple Yes will not cut it)!

I modified the G. Analytics code as following:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-19629541-5']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowHash', false]);
_gaq.push(['b._setAccount', 'UA-19629541-5']);
_gaq.push(['b._setAllowHash', true]);

for (var i=0;i<=10;i++) {
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(['b._trackPageview']);
}
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async =   true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') +         '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

It will now spawn multiple visits and visitors when you run it. You can see that the second number on __utma changes for every pageview, that number is the visitorId, when it changes it means you get a new visitor

The problem is that the stats I get now look like this:

- Visits: *1,785*
- Unique Visitors: *1,781*
- Pageviews: *2,188*
- Pages / Visit: *1.23*
- Avg. Visit Duration: *00:00:03*
- Bounce    Rate: *96.13*% %
- New    Visits: *99.78*%

Please not the extreme **decrease** in avg. visit duration!

before they were similar to this:

- Visits: *135*
- Unique Visitors: *118*
- Pageviews: *383*
- Pages / Visit: *2.84*
- Avg. Visit Duration: *00:04:22*
- Bounce Rate: *57.78*%
- % New Visits: *68.89*%

Now my question: How would I need to modify the G. Analytics Code (if at all posible) to make it look similar to this:

- Visits: 135 * **10** = *1350*
- Unique Visitors: 118 * **10** = *1180*
- Pageviews: 383 * **10** = *3830*
- Pages / Visit: *2.84*
- Avg. Visit Duration: *00:04:22*
- Bounce Rate: *57.78%*
- % New Visits: *68.89%*

so basically increase the amount of Visits, Unique Visitors, Pageviews **10** fold yet leave the other stats the same.

**Examples on http://jsfiddle.net are greatly welcomed**

PS: sorry for my bad English (not my mother tongue)

Comment: This seems very logical to me, since you create 10 pageviews in an extreme short amount of time, the visit duration of course decreases drastically.

Comment: Never said that it illogic I am just asking if there is a way to really fake an Google analytics report - we are trying to fake our own reports so that we can check for patterns (like decrease in visit duration)

Comment: I would hope Google Analytics wouldn't be fooled this easily.

Comment: well me to but it is... and I want to know to what extend this can be done

Comment: Chriswede, Were you able to solve the Pages / Visit, Avg. Visit Duration, Bounce Rate, or New Visits stats problem within your Google Analytics code? I saw how in your code you were able to get the visitor numbers up, but the other stats were still at the old numbers. Any insight on this would be great. I am trying to do the same thing as you, and would like to know if you were able to solve your problem. Thanks!
Travis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics defines timeOnPage and timeOnSite on server side, the code is based on the time elapsed between the pageviews you sent. Since all this is done server side there's no way to fake this unless you space out your pageviews by the amount of time you wish to fake.

You also need to send more than 1 pageview per tracker to get the correct amount of pages/visit. Currently everytime you switch between the 2 trackers you reset cookies and the previous visitorId is lost forever.

So you want to do something like this:

- Create first tracker
- Fire a pageview
- wait something between 1 and 2 seconds
- Fire another pageview
- Maybe fire a third pageview after another 1 or 2 seconds 80% of the time to get closer to the right average.
- Create a new tracker
- rinse repeat

I would say that you probably want to introduce some more randomness still keeping the same average. For example in order to get the right BounceRate you'd need to have 57% of the visits firing a single pageview. And in order to get the right New Visitors metric you need to come back with one of those old ids but within a new visit to spawn a returning visitor. You can trigger a new visit by deleting the __utmb or __utmc cookies, or just waiting longer than 30min between a new pageview.

As you can see the closer you want to fake the numbers with the true the harder it might get.

This now becomes a little impractical to live in a single page script. Since it may take a couple seconds to complete and you probably want to emulate this thousands of times. So maybe it's better to create this use a headless browser like [phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/) that you can trigger multiple simultaneous instances of to get the results you want.

I wonder what kind of analysis you're planning to extract from these. Depending on the type of analysis what you already have is enough or maybe the effort to have a better emulation is not worth the insight.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to do this within one web page.  The problem is that whenever you reset the hash it spawns a new session which will cause the first "visitor" to leave, lowering avg. visit of duration and increasing the bounce rate.

I believe you could accomplish everything except for the Unique Visitors * 10 requirement by doing the following:

- Create a basic HTML page that just has the standard Google Analytics code in it, we'll call this `ga.htm`.
- Create an include file that has 9 0x0 sized iFrames, each with the `src` of `ga.htm`, we'll call this `include-ga.htm`.
- Inclue the `include-ga.htm` file at the bottom of all your pages.

This should artificially make GA think the user is viewing 10 pages at once which should multiply all your stats in unison, except for Unique Visitors.

Comment: Why stop at 9? You could do thousands, and configure each to refresh once every minute with a setTimeout. Let it set for a few minutes, and you'll have thousands of visits, each several minutes long.

Comment: wount the combinstion of my and your method allow me (with a little tweaking) to increase all even the unique visitor count?

Comment: @yahelc I stopped at 9 because he wanted 10x the number of visits.  Oops I guess that should be 10 LOL.

Comment: @Chriswede I don't think that would work, if you reset the session on any page it resets it for the whole session, i.e. all pages on your site.  The only way to do that would be to do it from separate browsers, or separate memory spaces.

Comment: Coundnt I also randomly display either script and through that get both effect (or at least have them balace each other out)?

Comment: No, because as soon as you kill a session it will prematurely end which causes the visit duration to be cut short.

Comment: How about something like 1 out of 10 times I display my modified code but choose 100 instead of 10?

Comment: The problem is that as soon as you run your modified code it ends the current session sooner than it should be and will throw off your numbers.  I really don't think you can have it both ways here.  But, go ahead and try it out and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

This is a proof of concept i assume.

Isn't your code already proving that you can manipulate GA stats, only hint of manipulation is the average visit time.

What i found interesting is how G.A determines if it is a unique visitor. You would think google does a check of some kind, IP/Mac/hostname or secret unique id on host. 
In the GA help it states

> Unique Visitors (or Absolute Unique Visitors):
>   Unique Visitors represents the number of unduplicated (counted only
>   once) visitors to your website over the course of a specified time
>   period. A Unique Visitor is determined using cookies.

Maybe your Avg. Visit Duration: can be manipulated in the GA cookie(s).
There is a jquery add-on/plugin which can be used to make cookies through java script.

Interested to know if your project is succesfull.

For completeness, [Google help on GA](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33087&topic=11285&ctx=topic)